# radius of a horizontal plane within a sphere

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to ascertain the radius of a horizontal plane sitting within a sphere at a certain point along the perpendicular centre axis of the sphere eg. I have a sphere with a radius of 2.1 metres. What is the radius of the circular horizontal plane that is 1.4 metres above the centre of the sphere

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\sqrt{{2.1}^2-{1.4}^2}.$

You can find this by drawing a figure with cross section of the sphere and the perpendicular plane.